# mysql-python connector work with python2.7 and 3.4 at the same time

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector, python-3.4

Python 2.7 and 3.4 co-exist in my mac-os. After installing the official mysql connector (downloaded from dev.mysql.com), `import mysql.connector` can only pass in python 2.7. Is there any way for the connector to work for both python versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can install the same connector via easy-install or pip from pypi

```
easy_install-3.4 mysql-connector-python
```

Comment: It worked for me using: easy_install-3.4 mysql-connector

Answer (score 0):

Relative to Python 3.6:

The official mysql connector only worked in python 2.7 after i installed it on OSX.
As an alternative I used the easy_install-3.6 python module integrated in python 3.6

> Go to directory: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin
>
> command: easy_install-3.6 mysql-connector-python